# Erro: "Cannot find symbol" - Instância de Classe dentro da Classe Main, com recurso a terminal Linux

Tags: java, linux, terminal

Tenho um exercício para resolver, que consiste em criar uma calculadora simples linguagem Java.

Tenho que através do Terminal, enviar os dois números, como argumentos para o meu programa. Estou a usar o seguinte comando de compilação:

```
 zeluis@zeluis-HP-EliteBook-8460p ~/NetBeansProjects/SOCP1/src/socp1 $ javac MainEX1.java
```

Só que me dá o seguinte erro:

```
    EX1.java
MainEX1.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
        CalculatorMethodos cM = new CalculatorMethodos();
        ^
  symbol:   class CalculatorMethodos
  location: class MainEX1
MainEX1.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
        CalculatorMethodos cM = new CalculatorMethodos();
                                    ^
  symbol:   class CalculatorMethodos
  location: class MainEX1
2 errors
```

Deixo em baixo a classe MAIN:

```
 int num1, num2, total = 0, opcCalc, vef = -1;
    CalculatorMethodos cM = new CalculatorMethodos();
  //read from keyboard
    Scanner lerDataKeyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);
    // BufferedReader lerDataKeyBoard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
/*    System.out.println("First number:\n");
    num1 = lerDataKeyBoard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Second number:\n");
    num2 = lerDataKeyBoard.nextInt(); */


    System.out.println("Introduza a operação:\n");
    System.out.println("'1' - SUM\n");
    System.out.println("'2' - SUBTRACT\n");
    System.out.println("'3' - MULTIPLY\n");
    System.out.println("'4' - DIVIDE\n");

    opcCalc = lerDataKeyBoard.nextInt();

    switch (opcCalc) {
        case 1:
           total = cM.add(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
            break;
        case 2:
          // total = cM.sub(args[0], args[1]);
            break;
        case 3:
         //   total = cM.sub(args[0], args[1]);
            break;
        case 4:
           // total = cM.div(args[0], args[1]);
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Resultado:" + total);

}
```

CLASSE CALCULATOR:

```
    public class CalculatorMethodos {

    private int total;

    public int add (int num1, int num2) {
        return total = num1 + num2;

    }
     public int sub(int num1, int num2) {
        return total = num1 - num2;

    }
      public int mult (int num1, int num2) {
        return total = num1 * num2;

    }
       public int div (int num1, int num2) {
        return total = num1 / num2;

    }
}
```

**SOLUÇÃO**
A solução para este erro, foi usar o comando javac com -cp e "..":

```
javac -cp .. MainEX1.java
```

**NOVO ERRO** - quando tento utilizar o comando `java MainEX1`

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MainEX1
```

Comment: E o código da classe *CalculatorMethodos* ?? Não tem ?

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza já vou colocar.

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza pode conferir

Comment: Você importou ele na classe *Main* ?

Comment: ele está dentro do mesmo Package :)

Comment: Você copiou o código da classe *CalculatorMethodos* e colou aqui ? Porque se foi isso falta fechar `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é problema de classpath.
Se todas as classes estão no mesmo pacote, compile com esse comando: `javac -cp .. MainEX1.java`

Você precisa informar ao compilador onde encontrar as classes necessárias para realizar a compilação. O `..` irá passar o diretório parent do diretório que você está executando o comando, no caso o: `zeluis@zeluis-HP-EliteBook-8460p ~/NetBeansProjects/SOCP1/src`

Dentre desse diretório será possível encontrar as classes `socp1.MainEX1` e `socp1.CalculatorMethodos`

Comment: funcionou, mas continuo com erro, quando tento por a correr o programa. Vou colocar no post original como edição

Comment: @bullprog É o mesmo problema. Só que nesse caso, além de colocar o diretório no classpath, você precisa chamar a classe pelo nome completo. O comando é: `java -cp .. socp1.MainEx1`